# Error running query on Master DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i run,below first query on  the database ,it returns records

Second one, running the same query on Master, gives an error:

> (Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.)

Why it works when I´m in grdconfig and doesn´t work when I´m in Master?

```
USE GRDCONFIG
SELECT DISTINCT
GRD.ID,GRD.NAME
FROM GRDCONFIG.DBO.GRDTABLE GRD
WHERE GRD.ACTIVE = 1
ORDER BY GRD.NAME ASC   



USE MASTER
SELECT DISTINCT
GRD.ID,GRD.NAME
FROM GRDCONFIG.DBO.GRDTABLE GRD
WHERE GRD.ACTIVE = 1
ORDER BY GRD.NAME ASC
```

Comment: it should not throw errors in both the cases,can you provide sample repro for us to test

Comment: Looks very similar to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/43276899/2224701

Comment: that time I did not made myself clear and i was thinking the problem was the alias.. now the same query runs on one database and doesn´t on Master, and nobody knows why